# Cannot locate displayed data in source code when Scraping with Scrapy

Tags: javascript, python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I am using a combination of Scrapy and regex to extract information from a Javascript item called 'DataStore.Prime' at the following page:

http://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/26/Seasons/4057/Stages/8273
The crawler I am using is this:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
import time
import re
import json


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "goal4"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/26"]
    download_delay = 1

    #rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/Seasons',)), follow=True, callback='parse_item')]
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/Tournaments/26'),deny=('/News', '/Fixtures'),), follow=False, callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):

regex = re.compile('DataStore\.prime\(\'ws-stage-stat\', { stageId: \d+, type: \d+, teamId: -?\d+, against: \d+, field: \d+ }, \[\[\[.*?\]\]', re.S)

        match2h = re.search(regex, response.body)

        if match2h is not None:
            match3h = match2h.group()

            match3h = str(match3h)
            match3h = match3h \
                 .replace('title=', '').replace('"', '').replace("'", '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '') \
                 .replace(' ', ',').replace(',,', ',') \
                 .replace('[', '') \
                 .replace(']','') \
                 .replace("DataStore.prime", '') \
                 .replace('(', ''). replace('-', '').replace('wsstagestat,', '')

            match3h = re.sub("{.*?},", '', match3h)
```

I am after the fixtures and scores that are displayed under the title 'FA Cup Fixtures'. You can select the game week you want using the calendar on the page itself. If you look at the source code though, it only contains the most recent game week (as this is last season now, that is the FA Cup Final).

The data for all previous weeks are not on the source code for this page. The calendar that you use seems to be generating an item within the code called:

```
stageFixtures.load(calendarParameter)
```

This (if I have understood correctly seems to control which game week is selected for display. What I want to know is:

1) Is that assumption correct?
2) Is there somewhere within the source code that is directing to other URL's storing the scores by week (I'm pretty sure there isn't but I'm really new to Javascript)?

Thanks

Comment: Your assumption seems like at least a good guess. And if it's true, then the data are most likely not embedded in the HTML you downloaded; the JavaScript function `stageFixtures.load` is probably downloading them via AJAX, which means they don't exist on the page until that JavaScript code gets run, which means that your scraper will never see them.

Comment: Try disabling Javascript in another browser and loading the page. If the data you want to scrape is not there, then you should try to locate the http requests that return the data you actually want. Webkit inspector Netowrking tab can be good for this; or Wireshark/Fiddler can be used to trace this stuff. If you need to simulate http requests I hear that postman for chrome is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `XHR` request going to load the fixtures. Simulate it and get the data.

For example, fixtures for `Jan 2014`:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from datetime import datetime
import requests

date = datetime(year=2014, month=1, day=1)
url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/8273/Fixtures/'

params = {'d': date.strftime('%Y%m'), 'isAggregate': 'false'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

fixtures = literal_eval(response.content)
print fixtures
```

Prints:

```
[
    [789692, 1, 'Saturday, Jan 4 2014', '12:45', 158, 'Blackburn', 0, 167, 'Manchester City', 1, '1 : 1', '0 : 1', 1, 1, 'FT', '0', 0, 0, 4, 1], 
    [789693, 1, 'Saturday, Jan 4 2014', '15:00', 31, 'Everton', 0, 171, 'Queens Park Rangers', 0, '4 : 0', '2 : 0', 1, 0, 'FT', '1', 0, 0, 1, 0],
    ...
]
```

Note that the response is not a json, but a basically a dump of Python's list of lists, you can load it with [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded
>   string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may
>   only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

Comment: hi again. that worked great. could you briefly explain to me what an xhr request is though please and whereabouts in the source code of the page in my question that reference is made to this? that would be a great help. thanks.

Comment: @user3045351 `XHR` is an [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest). Whenever you choose something in the calendar, there is a request going to the server. You can observe it in the browser developer tools.

Comment: i have asked another question at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343611/xmlhttprequest-mimicking-script-works-on-one-web-page-but-not-another where I have tried to locate with the source code in developer tools where the URL 'tournamentsfeed' is, but have been unable to do so...reason being in the question i have asked, the above method for obtaining data from the website server is not returning the same data as that on the page when i am looking at the premier league rather than the FA Cup. Can you tell me where I should be looking in the source code for this URL?