# Using range of dates to iterate through series of date stamped XHR requests

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I have some code that is a development of the answer I got to the question I asked here:

[Cannot locate displayed data in source code when Scraping with Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233855/cannot-locate-displayed-data-in-source-code-when-scraping-with-scrapy/25234506?noredirect=1#comment39338041_25234506)

My development of this answer is to iterate through a series of dates in a range and obtain the data I am after for each of these dates (idea being that if there is no data for that date, I will get blank returned).

The code is like so:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td
from ast import literal_eval
from datetime import datetime
import requests

d1 = date(2013,11,01)
d2 = date(2014,5,31)

delta = d2 - d1


for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    time1 =  str(d1 + td(days=i))
    time2 = time1.split("-", 1)[0]
    time3 = time1.split("-", -1)[1]
    time4 = time1.rsplit("-", 1)[-1]

    time2 = int(time2)
    time3 = int(time3)
    time4 = int(time4)

    date = datetime(year=time2, month=time3, day=time4)
    print date

    url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/8273/Fixtures/'

    params = {'d': date.strftime('%Y%m'), 'isAggregate': 'false'}
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36'}

    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

    fixtures = literal_eval(response.content)
    print fixtures
```

Rather than giving me the fixtures just for any given day, this code is giving me the fixtures for the whole of the month in which that date falls.

The code then proceeds to fall over a random points during the iteration process and throws up the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\newtets\newtets\spiders\test3.py", line 32, in <module>
    fixtures = literal_eval(response.content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(expr, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What I would like to know is:

1) Why is this code structure not returning either/or fixtures from that day/null if there are no fixtures?

2) What is the cause of this error and why does it keep occurring at random points during the execution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if `<!DOCTYPE` is in the line before your use `literal_eval`

```
fixtures = (response.content)
if not "<!DOCTYPE " in fixtures:
    fixtures = literal_eval(response.content)
```

Probably better to use a `try/except` catching the specific exception.

Your code completes successfully the only lines the cause the error were the ones containing `<!DOCTYPE` which I imagine are not relevant for what you are trying to do, when printed it is html.

Something like the following should work:

```
try:
    fixtures = literal_eval(response.content)
except SyntaxError:
    pass
print fixtures
```

There is an interesting part of the output:

```
<h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

There must be some part you are scraping the requires some sort of autorisation.

You may need to pass the day also `%d`:

```
params = {'d': date.strftime('%Y%m%d'), 'isAggregate': 'false'}
```

If you print params before the change date is just year and month, I imagine you want the days to get different fixtures over the month.

Comment: hello again. the above worked great for fixing the issue with the code causing an error, but I've still got the issue where I am getting a whole month's fixtures for each corresponding day iterated through in that month. i don't have the same forbidden access error as you btw.

Comment: I caught all the dodgy lines and had a look, there was an odd one in there, I will have a look at the rest, I missed that part

Comment: ah right...we as long as i can see the fixtures i am happy with not being able to see anything else. any thoughts on the date range problem?

Comment: what should the params "d" value look like?

Comment: honest answer is i have no idea. in the example i am basing my iterative version on, the date value in question was hardcoded as thus: 'date = datetime(year=2014, month=1, day=1)' if that is any help? thanks.

Comment: I changed your code, it goes day by day through the month now which I think makes more sense

Comment: actually, now ive said that, i've noticed some dates are missing...for example january 4th of this year was a match day, but no results are returned!?!

Comment: `[[789692,1,'Saturday, Jan 4 2014','12:45',158,'Blackburn',0,167,'Manchester City',1,'1 : 1','0 : 1',1,1,'FT','0',0,0,4,1]
,[789693,1,'Saturday, Jan 4 2014','15:00',31,'Everton',0,171,'Queens Park Rangers',0,'4 : 0','2 : 0',1,0,'FT','1',0,0,1,0]` I get loads of results for the fourth

Comment: try running it multiple times. on some runs i seem to not be getting all the day's data through. the 4th and 5th of january are not populated on every run though for some reason...

Comment: might need to sleep between calls I keep getting the results fine, I ran it ten times

Comment: i think that will resolve it...i think jan 4th/5th is a hotspot because there are lots of blank calls returned due to the long gap in days between the 2nd and 3rd round.

Comment: let me know how it goes, I don't seem to have any issues.