# Using if/elif with Python list of lists response from web page

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. An earlier question I have asked in relation to this has become a little muddied in some of the comments, so I thought it best to start again. I have the following code which is simulating a series of date stamped XHR requests to a web page to grab the data contained within:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td
from ast import literal_eval
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import time
import re

d1 = date(2013,11,01)
d2 = date(2014,5,31)

delta = d2 - d1


for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    time1 =  str(d1 + td(days=i))
    time2 = time1.split("-", 1)[0]
    time3 = time1.split("-", -1)[1]
    time4 = time1.rsplit("-", 1)[-1]

    time2 = int(time2)
    time3 = int(time3)
    time4 = int(time4)

    date = datetime(year=time2, month=time3, day=time4)


    url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/8273/Fixtures/'

    params = {'d': date.strftime('%Y%m%d'), 'isAggregate': 'false'}
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36'}

    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)


    try:
        fixtures = literal_eval(response.content)
        fixtures = str(fixtures)

        if fixtures is not None:

            fixtures = re.sub("\[", '', fixtures)
            fixtures = re.sub("\], ", ',\n', fixtures)
            fixtures = re.sub("\'", '', fixtures)
            fixtures = re.sub("\]", '', fixtures)

            print fixtures 
            time.sleep(1)

        elif fixtures == []:

           print "No Fixtures Today: " + date
           time.sleep(1) 

    except SyntaxError:

        print "Error!!!"
        time.sleep(1)
```

Not every date within that range will have data in it. If a request is made for a date that has no data, the response will print like this '[]'. The data being returned I am told is a Python list of list and not a json.

Given that I have converted the variable 'fixtures' to a string, I thought that the logic 'elif fixtures ==[]' would be sufficient to print what I require, however this is not working.

Can anyone suggest what I should change to get '"No Fixtures today:" date' printed as part of my elif statement?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just keep it as a list?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a reason I  would keep the list as is, I am not sure why you want it as a string.
Anyway this will work:

```
try:
    fixtures = literal_eval(response.content)
    if fixtures: # will be True if there is no falsey values like [] etc..
        fixtures = str(fixtures) # make string in here where needed

        fixtures = re.sub("\[", '', fixtures)
        fixtures = re.sub("\], ", ',\n', fixtures)
        fixtures = re.sub("\'", '', fixtures)
        fixtures = re.sub("\]", '', fixtures)

        print fixtures
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
       print "No Fixtures Today: " + date.isoformat() # cannot use `date` it is not a string
       time.sleep(1)
```

Outputs:

```
No Fixtures Today: 2013-11-01T00:00:00
No Fixtures Today: 2013-11-02T00:00:00
No Fixtures Today: 2013-11-03T00:00:00
No Fixtures Today: 2013-11-04T00:00:00
No Fixtures Today: 2013-11-05T00:00:00
No Fixtures Today: 2013-11-06T00:00:00
No Fixtures Today: 2013-11-07T00:00:00
785460, 1, Friday, Nov 8 2013, 19:45, 185, Bristol Rovers, 0, 100, York, 0, 3 : 3, 1 : 2, 1, 0, FT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
785442, 1, Friday, Nov 8 2013, 20:00, 5955, AFC Wimbledon, 0, 17, Coventry, 0, 1 : 3, 0 : 0, 1, 0, FT, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0
785433, 1, Saturday, Nov 9 2013, 13:00, 164, Grimsby, 0, 186, Scunthorpe, 0, 0 : 0, 0 : 0, 0, 0, FT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
785429, 1, Saturday, Nov 9 2013, 14:00, 1976, Boreham Wood, 0, 322, Carlisle, 0, 0 : 0, 0 : 0, 0, 0, FT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
785430, 1, Saturday, Nov 9 2013, 15:00, 1978, St.Albans, 0, 99, Mansfield, 0, 1 : 8, 1 : 2, 1, 0, FT, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0,
785431, 1, Saturday, Nov 9 2013, 15:00, 28, Milton Keynes Dons, 0, 201, Halifax, 0, 4 : 1, 1 : 0, 1, 0, FT, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
785432, 1, Saturday, Nov 9 2013, 15:00, 1386, Tamworth, 0, 258, Cheltenham, 0, 1 : 0, 1 : 0, 1, 0, FT, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
```

If you want the date like  `Fri Nov  1 00:00:00 2013`

use `date.ctime()`

`if fixtures:` will be False if your data returns an `empty list`,`string`, `tuple` `None` etc.., they are falsey `values` in `python`.  So if fixtures contains data it will print it `else` it will `print "No Fixtures Today: "` ...

```
In [1]: l =[]

In [2]: if l:
   ...:     print "Foo" # no output
   ...:     

In [3]: l =[1] # now l has an element

In [4]: if l:
    print "Foo" # this time `if l` is True so we get output
   .
  ..:     
  Foo

In [7]: l = []
In [8]: l is None
Out[8]: False
```

Comment: that worked great, thanks. could you explain a bit more what your first hashed out comment means though please, i dont quite get it...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because you are comparing the string `fixtures` with the list `[]`. While you could use `elif fixtures == '[]':`, converting a list to a string like that and then stripping out the brackets is generally a bad idea. Try leaving it as a list and use `string.join` instead:

```py
fixtures = literal_eval(response.content)
if fixtures is not None and len(fixtures) > 0: # If there are fixtures
    print ",\n".join([", ".join(str(x) for x in fixture) for fixture in fixtures]) # `fixtures` is a nested list
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    print "No fixtures today: " + str(date)
    time.sleep(1)
```

If there are fixtures (say, `fixtures` contains `[['fixture1', 'A'], ['fixture2', 'B'], ['fixture3', 'C']]`), your output will look like

```py
fixture1, A,
fixture2, B,
fixture3, C
```

as with your original code, because `",\n".join` inserts a comma and a newline between the items of `fixtures`. If there are no fixtures, output will remain as expected. Note that `date` is also converted to a string before printing.

#### An explanation:

After loading the fixtures using `literal_eval`, this code checks that a) `fixtures` is not `None` and b) `fixtures` contains items (`len(fixtures) > 0`). If both is true, we enter the first branch.

```py
print ",\n".join([", ".join(str(x) for x in fixture) for fixture in fixtures])
```

There, we go through each `fixture` in `fixtures` and join it with `", "`(`", ".join`does the joining), but only after converting each item to a string (we cannot join other types) using `str(x) for x in fixture`. This gives us a list of strings like `["fixture1, A", "fixture2, B", "fixture3, C"]`. We then join up all the items in that list with `",\n"` to create the desired output.

Should one of the conditions be false, then there are no fixtures, and we can output `"No fixtures today"`.

Comment: this produces the following error: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\newtets\newtets\spiders\test3.py", line 53, in <module>
    print ",\n".join(fixtures)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found'

Comment: Can you tell me what `fixtures` looks like (e.g. do a `print fixtures` before the `if`-statement)

Comment: i have developed this solution from an answer given at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233855/cannot-locate-displayed-data-in-source-code-when-scraping-with-scrapy/25234506?noredirect=1#comment39338041_25234506 where the person answering states that the response returned is a python list and not a json. im still learning the ropes with python and particularly using it for webscraping, so i cant tell you why the data returned is not a json, but apparently it is not.

Comment: in answer though, with brackets and commas stripped from a string derived from the response, the output looks like this: 785460, 1, Friday, Nov 8 2013, 19:45, 185, Bristol Rovers, 0, 100, York, 0, 3 : 3, 1 : 2, 1, 0, FT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,

Comment: Does this work? Now, the code also joins the nested lists into strings.

Comment: ok that now works, thanks a lot. please could you talk me through why it is necessary to state 'for x in fixture' and 'for fixture in fixtures'? also, which one is numeric and which one character based? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is failing long before you get to the `elif` line.

Consider these two lines from your program:

```
    fixtures = str(fixtures)
    if fixtures is not None:
```

When the second line executes `fixtures` is, and is always, a `str`. It is never anything else. In particular, it is never `None`.

The expression `fixtures is not None` is a tautology. `fixtures` is always, under every circumstance, `not None`, so the expression is always true.

Therefore, the `if` section will always execute, and the `elif` section will never execute. It doesn't matter what you do to the `elif` expression. It will never be evaluated.

And here is how I would fix it:

```
try:
    fixtures=literal_eval(response.content)

    if fixtures != []:
        print ',\n'.join(', '.join(str(f) for f in f) for f in fixtures)
    else:
       print "No Fixtures Today: " + str(date)

except SyntaxError:
    print "Error!!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you should use:

```
elif fixtures == '[]':
```

fixtures is a string, so a string should be '[]' with quotes.