# XMLHttpRequest mimicking script works on one web page, but not another

Tags: python, json, xmlhttprequest

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows 8 64 bit. I have some code that iterates through a series of XHR requests to pull down FA Cup data from a website. Each value in the dictionary 'year_tournament_map' represents the ID code for each season's FA Cup, which are parsed in turn.

The code for this is below:

```
import json
import requests
import time

from datetime import date, timedelta

year_tournament_map = {
    2013: 8273,
    2012: 6978,
    2011: 5861,
    2010: 4940,
    2009: 3419,
    2008: 2689,
    2007: 2175,
    2006: 1645,
    2005: 1291,
    2004: 903,
    2003: 579,
    2002: 421,
    2001: 243,
    2000: 114,
    1999: 26,
}

years = sorted(year_tournament_map.keys())
url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/%s/Fixtures/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36'}

for year in years:
    start_date = date(year, 11, 1)
    end_date = date(year + 1, 5, 31)
    delta = end_date - start_date

    for days  in range(delta.days + 1):
        time.sleep(0.5) 

        test_date = start_date + timedelta(days=days)

        params = {'d': str(test_date).replace('-', ''), 'isAggregate': 'false'}
        response = requests.get(url % year_tournament_map[year], params=params, headers=headers)

        try:
            json_data = response.content.replace("'", '"').replace(',,', ',null,')
            fixtures = json.loads(json_data)

        except ValueError:
            print "Error!!!"

        else:

            if fixtures:  # If there are fixtures
                print ",\n".join([", ".join(str(x) for x in fixture) for fixture in fixtures])  # `fixtures` is a nested list

            else:
               print "No Fixtures Today: %s" %  test_date
```

This works great, so I decided to experiment using this method on other tournaments, for example the English Premier League. I replaced the above dictionary with the following one, which has the ID codes for the Premier League instead of the FA Cup:

```
year_tournament_map = {
 1999: 2,
 2000: 85,
 2001: 191,
 2002: 299,
 2003: 429,
 2004: 594,
 2005: 836,
 2006: 667,
 2007: 1256,
 2008: 1539,
 2009: 1849,
 2010: 2458,
 2011: 2935,
 2012: 3389,
 2013: 3853,
 2014: 4311, }
```

When run however, this does not work as anticipated. The second season produces international fixtures and the fourth some fixtures from either the Finnish league or cup. It then falls over with an error saying I am trying to print to screen none ASCII/Unicode characters.

I was advised that the item "url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/tournamentsfeed/%s/Fixtures/'" can be observed using my browser development tools, but I was unable to locate it.

What I would like to know is:

1) Am I using the correct URL for the XHR on the Premier League data
2) Where in the sourcve code reference to the above URL can be found
3) Why my code is returning irrelevant/incorrect data in relation to what is on the page that I am browsing [here](http://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2).

Thanks

Comment: You don't mention your browser, but for *most* browsers, `F12` opens the tools.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher ive located the dev tools fine, i just cant find reference to anywhere within the page source code where a submission is made to 'tournamentsfeed'. I can see where the Javascript is the powers the calendar for selecting dates, but not where this submission goes to. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved in the end once I got to grips with the Google Chrome Development Tools a little more. On the 'Console' tab of the Dev tools, if you right click you get an option to turn on XMLHTTPRequests. Once this is done, when you change the dates on the calendar you see the XHR submission to 'tournamentsdfeed'. For some reason on the Premier League data the numeric season identifiers are different than those displayed in the address bar at the top of the page. With the FA Cup data this is not the case.

The dictionary used for this should read:

```
year_tournament_map = {
 1999: 2,
 2000: 89,
 2001: 213,
 2002: 359,
 2003: 542,
 2004: 803,
 2005: 1208,
 2006: 937,
 2007: 2025,
 2008: 2539,
 2009: 3115,
 2010: 4345,
 2011: 5476,
 2012: 6531,
 2013: 7794,
 2014: 9155, }
```

Thanks